# contact form including referral of previous page

Tags: php, forms, http-referer

I have a php contact form using POST and I want to automatically include the referring page on the form, that is the website linking to the contact form.  This would normally be within my website.

For example,

www.website.com/nothere.php
returns
404.php (with www.website.com/nothere.php as the address)

on the 404 page I have a link to feedback.php which is a contact form.

I want the referring URL (in this case "www.website.com/nothere.php") included on the submitted form.

I understand I can use this code:

```
$ref = getenv("HTTP_REFERER");
```

So, I added that to the php at the top of the page (here is a snippet):

```
$SendTo = "web@website.com";
$Subject = "Website Feedback";
$FromString = "From: ".$_POST['eaddress']."\r\n";
$ref = getenv("HTTP_REFERER");
```

But how do I code the indhold so the referral is printed on the email?

```
$Indhold .= "Referring page: ".$_POST['$????']."\n";
```

Can someone help with what I need to add to the above line? Or do I need to go about this in a different way?

Many thanks!
Andy

Answer (score 2):

Put a hidden input field into your contact form, that contains the referer:

```
<form ...>
...
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>" name="referer" />
...
</form>
```

Then you can access it with `$_POST['referer']` when sending the email.

Comment: That's the trick Jan, thank you very much.  Now I have another question.  Can I list more than one referral, say the last 5 pages they looked at (whether on my website or elsewhere)?

Comment: You'd have to manually track those referrals. In a session for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Well .. you can indeed use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] for this.
To include it just write something like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="referer" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" />
```

in your contact form.

And then, when you compose the message just do :

```
$Indhold .= 'Referring page: '.$_POST['referer']."\n";
```

Comment: Thanks Sorin, that worked although I saw Jan's answer first ;)  Now I have another question. Can I list more than one referral, say the last 5 pages they looked at (whether on my website or elsewhere)?

Comment: Sadly only the last referer is stored in that variable (or in any other from PHP). If you want to do what you described you need to track them yourself (but as an external referer .. you can have only one).

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything you should know that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is set by the client. This means that it can contain anything. If you really need to know the referrer then at least make sure that it is a URL and that it does not point to just any website.

For example:

```
$ref = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_REFERER', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
if ( ! preg_match('/^http:\/\/website.com/', $ref)) {
    $ref = '(Unknown URL...)';
}
```

If you just use `HTTP_REFERER` without checking it first then some bad guy can set it to a URL that installs a virus on the machine. In other words: Do not use it unless you check it.

Comment: wow, ok, thanks Sverri.  I added your line of code (and changed to my website.com) and I changed hidden field to text.  So now the referral URL is there to be tampered with.  However, the email still received, even if I changed the URL to dodgywebsite.com etc etc.  That is just a link sent in an email, so how would it install something unless we clicked on it?

Comment: ps. you can see the testing form I use at http://www.monkeyshrine.com/badlink.php