# contact form including referral of previous page button (multiple on one page)

Tags: php, variables, contacts

I asked a similar question over here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856915/contact-form-including-referral-of-previous-page).

"I have a php contact form using POST and I want to automatically include the referring page on the form, that is the website linking to the contact form. This would normally be within my website."  I now have HTTP_REFERER working fine on my contact form to show the previous page link.

My next step is to have the same/similar result, but the referring page has a number of tours listed on the same page, so just including the URL isn't enough.  I want to know which link/button they clicked to find the contact form.

Here is an example:
On tours.php I have the following code (multiple times on the same page):

```
<a href="<?php echo($domain); ?>/contact/booknow.php" </a>
```

I could change that to:

```
  <a href="<?php echo($domain); ?>/contact/booknow.php?tourname" </a>

<a href="<?php echo($domain); ?>/contact/booknow.php?tourname2" </a>
```

On the contact form I want to store that they came from tours.php and tourname2, etc.

So how can I store that information on the contact form, so I know which button they clicked on (which tour they are interested in)?

Or do I need to add another variable in the link on the tour.php page?

Many thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 1):

```
booknow.php?tourname1
booknow.php?tourname2
booknow.php?tourname3
```

When clicked, your next page will have access to $_GET['tourname1'] or $_GET['tourname2'] or $_GET['tourname3'] so you can test if they exists and you'll know on which link your visitor clicked.

I would suggest to change a bit for something like this :

```
booknow.php?tourname=1
booknow.php?tourname=2
booknow.php?tourname=3
```

So you can check if "tourname" exist and if so get its value "$_GET['tourname']".
Here you go :

```
$ref_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$ref_link = 0;
if( isset($_GET['tourname']) ) {
    $ref_link = $_GET['tourname'];
}
```